# Create system to run without internet and sync when get Online

Tags: asp.net, synchronization, offline

I am Creating POS system in C# MVC with SQL server database. I want my system to be able to work when No internet and whenever I re connect to the internet, system should be synchronized with live.

I have searched from internet but In all solution they suggested some javascript coding. but i have already created system in C# MVC. 
So how can i change my existing system to be able to work in offline mode?

Comment: Unclear, broad. You already mention a "system with SQL" which is how you'd persist data, whether or not that data is "synced" elsewhere. If you have an "online" system with "offline" clients (that will need to sync), then that's the architecture you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look into MS SQL Server Replication?

With Replication you can replicate your Local Database against Remote database either on demand / scheduled.

Replication Types: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152565(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: thanks. you are talking about database but how my application will run offline in client's pc

Comment: you would need some sort of storage to store data...you gonna have to store within a LOCAL Database Hosted on Client PC or clients LAN.

Comment: I have seen in one POS that when i am loading site first time, some process is downloading some css,scripts,and images and storing in local storage. then when i load site without internet, some files and re-downloaded and site work perfectly without internet.

but i could not understand what happened
I really need to implement this thing in my system.

Comment: @Bharat Did you got any solution to sync the Offline Db with your cloud DB?